# Defining Firefox extension preferences dynamically

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension that implements a bunch of little functions that can be called from a context menu in Firefox.  I made a preferences window that shows a radiogroup for each preference, allowing the function to be shown in the main Firefox menu, to be shown in a submenu created by the extension, or to be hidden.  This works exactly the same way for each extension function with only the following things changing: the preference id, the preference name, the called function name, and the label of each radio group.  Is it possible to create an array containing those four strings for each function and then to define all of the preferences dynamically, rather than copying and pasting the same code for each preference?

I am pretty sure it is possible to define the XUL in my preferences window dynamically.  However, I am not sure about defining the default preferences in the defaults folder using the pref() command (I am not sure how to access strings defined somewhere else in the extension).  I am also not sure if the  definitions of the preferences.xul file can be defined dynamically or if they need to be typed out.

Also, do you think this is a good or bad idea?  I was thinking it would make adding/removing functions easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me. Anything that you can do in a static XUL file you can do dynamically by creating the contents of the XUL window using DOM functions (including the contents of `preferences.xul`, whatever they may be). As far as default values are concerned, you can set them manually using the preferences API on browser startup if there are no values already set. You can use the [observer service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications) to handle the `profile-after-change` notification. Use the [preferences API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Preferences) to check whether your prefs already have a value set and, if not, set them to the default value of your choice.

To check whether a pref already exists, use the appropriate [`nsIPrefBranch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefBranch) method to try to get it. If an exception is thrown then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about using the preferences API to set up the preferences.  I will try that.  Before your response, I had gotten something close to working by using JSON to save an array containing the preferences as a string, but being able to save them as individual preferences should be cleaner.

Comment: Is it important to use the profile-after-change notification to initialize the preferences?  My extension has an init() function that is called by a "load" event listener, so I was considering putting the preferences set up in there.  I would have to learn more about extensions to do the profile-after-change notification.

Comment: I implemented my dynamic preferences using my init() function and everything seems to work.  Just to sketch it out in case anyone looks at this later: I stored all of preferences as an array of strings stored as a field in my main extension object.  Then I wrote a function to loop on this array and create all of the necessary XUL for each string with id's formed using that string and set onpaneload of the prefpane to this function.  Another function loops over the array and sets each pref to a default value in init() if it is not set.

Comment: Just be aware that init() will be called every time you open a new window. I guess if you are just checking for missing values that doesn't really matter. So profile-after-change is probably more correct but your solution is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll try to switch to using profile-after-change, but I don't really understand the page you linked to that describes.  I'll ask about that in a new question though.

Comment: After I posted this question I learned about [add-on bootstrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) for which it is required that all preferences be defined dynamically, so it is actually pretty common in recent add-ons.  One nice method of the [preferences service nsiPrefService()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefService) is `getDefaultBranch()`.  Setting the values of this branch is equivalent to using a `defaults/preferences.js` file except it can set the default values dynamically.